# Do ALL documents need to be translated & notarised for the Spanish Digital Nomad visa?

Tags: united-kingdom, visa, spain, digital-nomads, translations

I am applying for the recently created [Digital Nomad visa for Spain](https://www.exteriores.gob.es/Consulados/londres/en/ServiciosConsulares/Paginas/Consular/Digital-Nomad-Visa.aspx).

At the bottom of the page it states (emphasis mine):

> SWORN TRANSLATIONS AND LEGALISATIONS
>
> **All documents must be translated** into Spanish by a Translator-Interpreter. It is possible to find a translator in the List of Translators-Interpreters registere​d in Spain.
>
> **All foreign documents must be legalized** by the consulates of the issuing country or, in the case of signatory countries to the Hague Convention of October 5, 1961, hold the Hague Apostille. Official documents issued by a Member State of the European Union, do not require legalization.

**Okay, but what constitutes a "document"?** This visa has a number of requirements: some are forms that are already in Spanish, some are forms issued by the UK government and some are simply written declarations or various bits of proof, like bank statements.

I've compiled a list of all the requirements and what **I** think needs doing but perhaps someone can clarify which need translation (and notarisation).

| Item | Needs translation | Needs notarisation | Comment |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| EX15 form | ❎ | ❎ | Already in Spanish |
| Passport | ❎ | ❎ | Translation not usually needed |
| Proof of address | ❓ | ❓ |  |
| Form 790 | ❎ | ❎ | Already in Spanish |
| Criminal Record | ☑️ | ☑️ | UK issued |
| Responsible Declaration | ❓ | ❓ |  |
| Company Contract | ❓ | ❓ |  |
| Certificate from Companies House | ☑️ | ☑️ | UK issued |
| Health Insurance Certificate | ☑️ | ☑️ | UK issued |
| S1 Form | ❎ | ❎ | Already in Spanish |
| A1 Form | ☑️ | ☑️ | UK issued |
| Financial Proof | ❓ | ❓ | E.g: bank statements |
| University Degree Certificate | ☑️ | ☑️ | UK issued |
| Civil Partnership Certificate | ☑️ | ☑️ | UK issued |

Comment: I don't see why any specific documents should be excluded from translation

Comment: Does the Company consent letter need to be translated by a Spanish Sworn translator? This is just a letter from the Managing Director to confirm I can work abroad, written and signed by him.

Comment: @PhoebeG I am not 100% certain but most likely, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's stupid. But that's how the burocreacy in Spain works. Certain discretion could be made but it's not guaranteed.

The proof of address is the only example I can think it's exempted since it's only for internal use of the embassy and not part of the visa application. I did my consular registration with non-translated proof of address.

| Item | Needs translation | Needs notarisation | Comment |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| EX15 form | ❎ | ❎ | Already in Spanish |
| Passport | ❎ | ❎ | Translation not needed |
| Proof of address | ❎ | ❎ | Usually not required |
| Form 790 | ❎ | ❎ | Already in Spanish |
| Criminal Record | ☑️ | ☑️ | UK issued |
| Responsible Declaration | ❎ | ❎ | You could write it in Spanish |
| Company Contract | ☑️ | ❓ | I'd say it's not needed to notarise since it's not a goverment-issued document |
| Certificate from Companies House | ☑️ | ☑️ | UK issued |
| Health Insurance Certificate | ☑️ | ☑️ | UK issued |
| S1 Form | ❎ | ❎ | Already in Spanish |
| A1 Form | ☑️ | ☑️ | UK issued |
| Financial Proof | ☑️ | ☑️ | If you can get the bank statements stamped |
| University Degree Certificate | ☑️ | ☑️ | UK issued |
| Civil Partnership Certificate | ☑️ | ☑️ | UK issued |

Comment: What do you mean by getting the bank statements stamped? By the bank?

Comment: @turnip yes, by the bank.

Answer (score 0):

The city of Barcelona [states](https://www.barcelona.cat/internationalwelcome/en/residency-digital-nomads-visa-and-permit)

> The documents provided must be translated into Spanish by means of sworn translation and be correctly legalised. In the case of multilingual standard EU forms, neither translation nor legalisation is required.

There are no exclusions from the requirements of translations